# How to display and use an object in the main Processing class

Tags: java, processing

I'm trying to create a game in Processing. Basically it's pong.
I have 3 classes. The main class(PongRunner), the class for the ball(PongBall) and the class for the racket(PongRacket).

I am trying to display the PongRacket object in the PongRunner class but, it does not get displayed. Here's my code:

The PongRacket class:

```
    // this is the class for the pong racket used in the game
    // it specifies the racket's attributes and methods

    public class PongRacket{

      // attributes of the pong racket
      private int racketWidth = (1/9)*width; // width of the racket
      private int racketHeight = (1/15)*height; // height of the racket
      private int startRacketXPosition = (4/9)*width; // x value for starting position of racket
      private int startRacketYPosition = (14/15)*height; // y value for starting position of racket

      // display the racket
      public void displayRacket(){
        fill(0, 0, 0); // color for racket is black
        rect(getStartRacketXPosition(), getStartRacketYPosition(), getRacketWidth(), getRacketHeight());
      }

      // move the racket
      public void moveRacket(){

      }

      // setters
      public void setRacketWidth(int myWidth){
        this.racketWidth = myWidth;
      }

      public void setRacketHeight(int myHeight){
        this.racketHeight = myHeight;
      }

      // getters
      public int getRacketWidth(){
        return this.racketWidth;
      }

      public int getRacketHeight(){
        return this.racketHeight;
      }

      public int getStartRacketXPosition(){
        return startRacketXPosition;
      }

      public int getStartRacketYPosition(){
        return startRacketYPosition;
      }

    } // end class PongRacket
```

The PongRunner class

```
    //this is the main class that runs the game
    // it consists of a racket
    // why doesn't the racket get displayed?

    PongRacket racket = new PongRacket(); // creates the racket object

    void setup(){
      size(width, height);
      frame.setResizable(true); // the frame can be resized now
    }

    void draw(){
      background(255); // color for background is white
      racket.displayRacket(); // why isn't this getting displayed?

    }
```

Whenever I call :

```
    racket.displayRacket(); // inside the PongRunner class
```

It does not work or display anything on the screen. How will I get it to work?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry, my question was not clear @ataylor. I am calling a method called displayRacket() on my racket object from PongRacket inside my PongRunner class but it does not work or display anything. How will I get to display it on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

I can spot two main issues:

1. You're creating a PongRacket() before calling `size()` (not recommended)
2. You're doing integer division (1/9), (1/15), (4/9), (14/15). If you println(); each of these you'll notice the result is 0 (`println(14/15);`). Please use floats instead (`println(14.0/15);`)

Here's a basic refactor:

```
PongRacket racket;

void setup() {
  size(width, height);
  frame.setResizable(true); // the frame can be resized now
  racket = new PongRacket(); // creates the racket object

}

void draw() {
  background(255); // color for background is white
  racket.displayRacket(); // why isn't this getting displayed?
}

public class PongRacket {

  // attributes of the pong racket
  private float racketWidth = (1.0/9)*width; // width of the racket
  private float racketHeight = (1.0/15)*height; // height of the racket
  private float startRacketXPosition = (4.0/9)*width; // x value for starting position of racket
  private float startRacketYPosition = (14.0/15)*height; // y value for starting position of racket

    // display the racket
  public void displayRacket() {
    fill(0, 0, 0); // color for racket is black
    rect(getStartRacketXPosition(), getStartRacketYPosition(), getRacketWidth(), getRacketHeight());
  }

  // move the racket
  public void moveRacket() {
  }

  // setters
  public void setRacketWidth(int myWidth) {
    this.racketWidth = myWidth;
  }

  public void setRacketHeight(int myHeight) {
    this.racketHeight = myHeight;
  }

  // getters
  public float getRacketWidth() {
    return this.racketWidth;
  }

  public float getRacketHeight() {
    return this.racketHeight;
  }

  public float getStartRacketXPosition() {
    return startRacketXPosition;
  }

  public float getStartRacketYPosition() {
    return startRacketYPosition;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @George Profenza, it worked. It was because I didn't use floats for the variables and I was creating the PongRacket() object before calling size just as you said. Thanks! I am trying to UpVote your answer but, it says I need to increase my reputation in order to vote. I joined recently.

Comment: However, whenever I resize the frame, the racket object does not resize too. How will I get the created PongRacket() to resize correctly as the width and height of the frame?

Comment: Because you set the dimensions once. Try updating them continously. For example you can add these lines at the top of the ```displayRacket()``` functions: ```racketWidth = (1.0/9)*width; // width of the racket
    racketHeight = (1.0/15)*height; // height of the racket```